# Booting with linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic causes wifi to be lost

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, wifi

My computer loses wifi connection when booted with "linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic". Why so ?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `dpkg -l | grep 4.4.0-62`

Comment: As well as the output for the same command on a working kernel version.  I'd bet that your wireless modules haven't been updated...

Comment: can you edit your question and show `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2` and `dkms status` if available.

Comment: Sure I will add both the details.

Comment: @Jeremy was right, this install fixed the issue. $ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source